# Stashed files showing untracked on other branches

Tags: git

I'm doing work on a branch, and I want to switch to a different branch to quickly change something else, so I do

```
git stash
```

then `git status` shows

```
On branch <branch-1>
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   <test-file>
```

So I swap to the second branch

```
git checkout <other-branch>
```

but when I then do

```
git status
```

it shows

```
On branch <branch-2>

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

the changed file (while tracked in the original branch) shows in the untracked list in the second branch even though its stashed. If its stashed, shouldn't it be hidden?

**EDIT-1**: I'm trying to stash changes to a binary file if that makes a difference.

**EDIT-2**: Full reproducable example

Have `branch-1`, and `branch-2`

On `branch-1` with changes to `file`

```
git add .
git stash
git checkout <branch-2>
```

then `git status` shows

```
On branch <branch-2>

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit per question edit: I'm afraid your example *isn't* reproducible.  Demonstration:

```
$ mkdir tstash
$ cd tstash
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo stash example > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 43629f2] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
$ echo file > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m "create file named 'file'"
[branch1 5e169b8] create file named 'file'
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git branch branch2 master
$ echo modify file >> file
$ git status 
On branch branch1
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

(At this point, I've re-created your setup according to your rules.)

```
$ git add .
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on branch1: 5e169b8 create file named 'file'
$ git checkout branch2
Switched to branch 'branch2'
$ git status
On branch branch2
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ ls
README
$
```

The file is not there, as one would (and you did) expect.

You'll need a better reproducer.  My new speculation is that this has something to do with case-insensitive file systems on Windows or macOS.  Other possibilities include badly behaved Git hooks and/or some tricky `.gitignore` items (in particular some file might be `.gitignore`-ed in the `branch1` tip commit, but not in the `branch2` tip commit).

#### Original answer to original question

The `git stash` command—at least when used the way you are using it—can only save *tracked* files.  Any untracked files *are not in Git*.  Files that are not in Git are not "on" any branch and therefore do not get swapped in and out when you change branches.  This is all very loosely and improperly phrased, but almost certainly covers what you're doing.

> If [a file is] stashed, shouldn't it be hidden?

No.  That's not what `git stash` is about.

I recommend that everyone—newbies and experienced Git users both—*avoid* `git stash` as much as possible.  It's full of many nasty traps for the unwary, and even those who are good at Git can fall afoul of some of its odder behaviors.  What `git stash` really does is make some commits (and then run `git reset --hard` for you).  The main thing that is special about these commits is that they are on *no* branch, which means it's easy to "un-stash" them on *any* branch later.  Unfortunately, they are then in a format that *most* Git commands don't deal with correctly, so that only the `git stash` command *can* be used with these on-no-branch commits, and if you need something that `git stash` is bad at—which is almost everything—you can't use the *rest* of Git to help you out.<sup>1</sup>

So just make ordinary commits instead.  To work temporarily on something else, on another branch, use `git worktree` (provided your Git is at least 2.5, preferably at least 2.15).

---

<sup>1</sup>Fortunately, there's `git stash branch`, which can turn an old stash *into* a branch.  So if you've made some stash(es) and need to convert them, you can use this.  Unfortunately, if you've used `git stash -u` or `git stash -a`, even this doesn't work: if you're stuck with this problem, $deity help you.

Comment: But what's weird is that it is a tracked file. It was tracked in the main branch, and is thus in the second branch created off of the main branch. I made a change to it in the second branch, stashed it, and when switched to main, it showed in the list as untracked.

Comment: Do you have a [mre]?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: Yup it ended up being an issue with changes to a gitignore file that differed between the two branches! Fixing that solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `git stash --include-untracked` if you also want to stash your untracked files

Comment: But the file *is* tracked.